# Error handling not working on run-time Error 9 in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply the error handling mechanism in  Excel VBA, I want to catch this "runtime error 9", but it's not working. 
I am using this userform_initialize() method/sub over and over again, each time I don't want to open this "SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm" workbook instead, I want to check if it's already open. if yes, then switch to that window or open that workbook.

I have tried `on error resume next` statement as well but still, it breaks on switching to window `"Windows("SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm "). Select"`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo OPEN_WB_ERR
    Windows("SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm").Select
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.RowSource = ("'X:\SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm'!SEARCH")
    Windows("PROFORMA_INVOICE.xlsm").Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
OPEN_WB_ERR:
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm"
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.RowSource = ("'X:\SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm'!SEARCH")

    Windows("PROFORMA_INVOICE.xlsm").Activate
Resume Next
End Sub
```

any advice will be helpful...

Comment: "Workbooks.Open" will select the file if it is already open, or open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim path As String, Fn As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Fn = "X:\SAMPLE UPDATE FILE.xlsm"

    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Fn)
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.RowSource = "'" & Fn & "'" & "!SEARCH"
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your setting in the VB editor (*Tools >> Options >> General tab >> Error Trapping*) for how errors are handled - if you have "Break on all errors" selected then it will always break regardless of any error handling you have set. "Break in Class module" is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

The Initialize event procedure runs when the form is first created, before it is shown. You should open your workbook before creating the form, not as part of that process. Try a procedure like the one below, to be installed in a standard code module.

```
Sub OpenUserForm()

    Dim MyForm As UserForm1

    ' open your workbook here
    Set MyForm = New UserForm1          ' this fires the Initialize event
    UserForm1.Show

    ' the code below runs when MyForm is closed
    Unload MyForm
    Set MyForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that a form by the name of *UserForm1* must exist. I recommend to give it another, more descriptive name. If you do that whatever name you give is the one to use in the Dim statement declaring *MyForm*.

Answer (score 1):

I use a WorkbookIsOpen function

```
Public function WorkbookIsOpen(byval strFile as string) as Boolean

Dim wbkCurr as excel.workbook

WorkbookIsOpen = false
For each wbkCurr in application.Workbooks
    If wbkCurr.name = strfile then
        WorkbookIsOpen = true
        Exit for
    Endif
Next wbkCurr 

End function
```

Pass just the file name and extension ie myworkbook.xlsx

Then I just adjust my logic accordingly